# How can I alias an single import?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working in a custom component. In this component, I call a subcomponent called `Card` like this:

```
import { Card } from "./Card";
```

And I am using it like that:

```
<Card></Card>
```

Everything is fine. Now here is the problem. It this custom component, I want to use a enum from the file "../../App/Models/Something". This Enum name is `Card`. I know that I could write

```
import * as Something from "../../App/Models/Something";
```

and do `Something.Card` in my component, but "Something" contains a lot of things I do not need. How can alias an single import?

I tried this but neither are working:

```
import { Card } as Something from "../../App/Models/Something";
import Card as Something from "../../App/Models/Something";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it! The correct way to import a single alias is:

```
import { Card as Something } from "../../App/Models/Something";
```

Read the documentation about import on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

**Syntax:**

> ```
> import defaultExport from "module-name";
> import * as name from "module-name";
> import { export } from "module-name";
> import { export as alias } from "module-name";
> import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
> import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
> import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
> import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
> import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
> import "module-name";
> var promise = import("module-name");
> ```

The one fixing your case is `import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";` [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias)